# decode querystring within context.Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-server-2008

i have an ashx file that requires some query-string values to deliver appropriate images.

The problem is some search engines urlencode then htmlencode those urls in their cache or when they index those.

So for example instead of getting

```
/preview.ashx?file=abcd.jpg&root=small
```

i get

```
/preview.ashx?file=abcd.jpg&amp;root=small
```

this basically throws off the `context.Request.QueryString["root"]` so it thinks that there's no variable **root**

i guess the second key in the querystring is **amp;root**  i.e the part after the & sign.

What i'm wondering is if there's a way to automatically html and urldecode the querystring on serverside so that the program doesn't get confused.

Comment: You tagged the question with `C` - did you mean `C#`?

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `context.Request.QueryString["root"]` (the _string_ `root`)

Comment: yes.. i meant c#... context.Request.QueryString["root"] should return small but it returns null because there's no such key as root.... there's a key amp;root

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no harm in calling `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` or `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` more than once.

```
string queryString = "/preview.ashx?file=abcd.jpg&amp;root=small";
var parsedString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(queryString);
var root = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(parsedString)["root"];
```

Comment: thanks... i actually was trying to avoid doing it that way... but i guess since there's no way to SET context.Request.QueryString after decoding it, that should work too. Was wondering if there was a way to decode it serverside so that i could leave the program out of it

Comment: Actually, wouldn't it be a problem if you had an encoded + sign in your original URL and you called decode twice? The first time, it would be decoded to +, but the second time, + would be decoded as a space. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @rar How about posting an example using for ex `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` so that we can talk on a concrete sample code.

Answer (score 11):

To URL encode and decode you can use the following methods:

```
string encoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);

string decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
```

I've seen instances in the past where the Query String has been doubly encoded. In which case you'll need to doubly decode — this may be your issue...

Answer (score 1):

WebUtility.UrlDecode(countyName)

Latest in .net core 6